# How to discern between results with and without defects using statistics?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I need advice on the statistical method, and I've included some preliminary findings from my dataset, which includes mean, standard deviation, and variance.

To distinguish between artifact-related and non-artifact-related data, I would like to receive the results from the mean, standard deviation, and variance formulation.

Can someone provide me with a statistical formula that will enable me to distinguish between artifact-free findings and those that are not?

[image]